# Using variables from a parent form on child form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Clicking an exit button on a form I made pops up another form, which is supposed to house the values of Wins and Losses.

How can I use the variable from the main form in the form that pops up? I'm very new programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//in child form...    
class Form_pop
{
    public Form_pop(int wins, int loses)
    {
        this.wins = wins;
        this.loses = loses;
    }

    int wins;
    int loses;

    private void Form_pop_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label_wins.Text = wins.ToString();
        Label_loses.Text = loses.ToString();
    }
}

//In parent form...
Form_pop form_pop = new Form_pop(yourWins, yourLoses);
form_pop.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass variables from main form to popup form via its constructor:

```
public class PopupForm : Form
{
    public PopupForm(int wins, int losses)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // use variables
    }
}
```

And pass them when create instance of form:

```
using(PopupForm popup = new PopupForm(winsValue, lossesValue))
      popup.ShowDialog();
```

Nice to read: [Passing Data Between Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of how to do so. It hasn't been tested but should give you a basic idea:

**Form 1**

```
// Within button click handler
Form2 secondForm = new Form2();
secondForm.setVariables(valueForWins, valueForLosses);
secondForm.show();
```

**Form 2**

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(){

    }

    public setVariables(int wins, int losses){
       // Set the values here
    }
}
```

Comment: in the //set values here part, what am I setting? Is this where the values from parent form are passed in?

Comment: This is where you display them on your labels. By calling this function, it will pass those values to the child form. Here you need labels or something on which to show the text